# Can we implement our own materials in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, shader

JavaFX has the [`abstract class Material`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Material.html) for representing materials of 3D surfaces. The current JDK gives only a [`PhongMaterial`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/PhongMaterial.html) implementation. I was looking into adding my own material (like Lambert or Blinn etc.) by extending `Material` similar to how `PhongMaterial` is implemented.

There are 2 problems I encountered:

1. The behavior (color calculation) specified in the `PhongMaterial` documentation is nowhere to be found - not in the class itself and not in the internal classes Iv'e looked at. It's *somewhere* in the JDK, but not so exposed. The `PhongMaterial` class only holds the properties and not the behavior, which I find strange to begin with.
2. `PhongMaterial` appears to be deeply coupled with internal classes:

   - `com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGPhongMaterial`, which according to some documentation is *the peer node created by the graphics Toolkit/Pipeline implementation*. This class specifies no behavior.
   - `com.sun.prism.PhongMaterial`, which *represents a phong material for retained mode rendering*.
   - `com.sun.prism.TextureMap` is *a wrapper class to hold map related information for the PhongMaterial*.

   None of these specify the material's behavior.

What are the steps to implement my own material? What classes do I need to write? For example, would I need a new `TextureMap` class which I will somehow inform Prism about?

Comment: Ah yes, you've made the same discovery I once did: the JavaFX documentation is awful.

Comment: @Michael That I already had an idea about. My problem here is not so much with the documentation as it is about the implementation.

Comment: So looking into it, Material has 2 `impl_` abstract methods which any subclass is required to override, and three methods related to a "dirty" flag. All three `impl_` methods are marked as deprecated and "will be removed in the next version". I think this is a strong indicator that you can basically not implement your own `Material`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the reply in the OpenJFX mailing list about creating materials:

> We don't currently plan any improvements in the area of 3D rendering. Even if we did, allowing application-defined materials would require some way for the application to provide the needed shader support for rendering such materials.

So the answer to the question is "No", and there are no plans to change that in the future.

Comment: Nice follow-up, you should mark this answer as correct once the [system lets you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @jewelsea I could have marked it as correct immediately, but didn't want to take James_D's points :) I guess it's the right thing to do anyway...

Comment: No, this is the most definitive answer. It is appropriate to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the `Material` class is not (currently) designed for subclassing. This is probably because a fixed public API has not yet been agreed on.

`Material` contains two abstract methods. In [JavaFX 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/paint/Material.java) these are

```
public abstract void impl_updatePG();
```

and

```
public abstract NGPhongMaterial impl_getNGMaterial();
```

These are marked `@Deprecated` and `@treatAsPrivate implementation detail`.

In [JavaFX 9](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/40510c800d46/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/paint/Material.java) the names change and the visibility changes to package-private:

```
abstract void updatePG();
```

and

```
abstract NGPhongMaterial getNGMaterial();
```

So it looks like the intention here is not to allow subclassing, but to have a design that will allow future (>9) versions to allow subclassing once an API has been decided on. Again, here I am reading between the lines to a large degree: users closer to the JavaFX team may have more complete information. FWIW, the current version of the source code contains the following comment:

> Material is not Paint
>   PhongMaterial maybe the first and only material
>   in FX8 (see 3D conceptual implementation for details)
>   Bump map:
>   Normal Map and Height Map -- We may generate a Normal Map when given a
>   Height Map
>   Displacement map? Not in FX8 -- May do Parallex correction
>   mapping to improve quality at performance cost
>   Support auto generated
>   Mipmap
>   No plan to support Multi-texture

Comment: Now that I think about it, it might be worthwhile to ask on the OpenJFX mailing list about future intentions.

Comment: Added the response from them in case you're interested.