# How to make a scaled JavaFX 3D texture Pixel-Perfect at different distances?

Tags: javafx, 3d, game-development

I am making an 8-bit game like Minecraft with Perspective Camera and SubScene and such, get this result from

```
new Box() {{
    setMaterial(new PhongMaterial() {{
        setDiffuseMap(new Image("img.png"));
    }});
}};
```

[image: its soooo blurry]
(if you can't see the image, the low res texture is blurry)
Help please?

**Edit:**

Minimal Reproducible Example

```
package com.example.jfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MRE extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Image img = new Image("example.png");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(
                new Box(500, 500, 500) {{ // Farthest back
                    setMaterial(new PhongMaterial() {{ // Diffuse Map
                        setDiffuseMap(img);
                    }});
                }},
                new Box(500, 500, 500) {{ // Middle
                    setMaterial(new PhongMaterial() {{ // Semi-working, but the black spots have a circle gradient, and it seems brighter
                        setDiffuseMap(img);
                        setSelfIlluminationMap(img);
                    }});
                    setTranslateZ(1000);
                }},
                new Box(500, 500, 500) {{ // Closest
                    setMaterial(new PhongMaterial() {{ // Nice and smooth, but if you get close enough, it is still blurry, and this takes up extra memory (I think)
                        setDiffuseMap(new Image("example.png", 1600, 1600, false, false, false));
                    }});
                    setTranslateZ(2000);
                }}
        ) {{
            setTranslateY(300);
        }}, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.setCamera(new PerspectiveCamera());
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

That looks like this:

[image: the three boxes and labels]

(sorry hard to write with mouse)

Number 1 is just the diffuse map, number 2 is diffuse map and self illumination map (that would mess up lighting in my game), and number 3 is workable if I have to, but that would take up a lot of memory, and still be a little fuzzy if you zoom in enough.

Here's the original texture, it's 8 by 8 pixels:

[image: the texture]

Just a red and black checkerboard pattern.

Comment: To prevent texture resizing, you need to ensure that your texture will fit exactly the size of the model surface you are mapping it to and that both are large enough with enough fidelity that the image will be clear when observed close up.  For information on different kinds of resizing for JavaFX (2D) images, see [JavaFX ImageView without any smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089304/javafx-imageview-without-any-smoothing).

Comment: Tried that, none of them worked

Comment: It will work.  Provide a [mcve].  Ensure that it includes both the complete code and images, so that your issue can be reproduced by copy and pasting your source with *no change or addition* and the only thing the code does is reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added a mre, what next?

Comment: You wait and see if anybody is interested in attempting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

3D modeling in general is a complex topic, this answer only discusses some relevant approaches to fit the question, and some items are not explained in full.

#### Background

To prevent texture resizing, you need to ensure that your texture will fit exactly the size of the model surface you are mapping it to and that both are large enough with enough fidelity that the image will be clear when observed close up.

For information on different kinds of resizing for JavaFX (2D) images, see [JavaFX ImageView without any smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089304/javafx-imageview-without-any-smoothing).  It is important to understand JavaFX 2D images and image resizing.  Any textures that you apply to a 3D model are set on the `PhongMaterial` of the 3D model as JavaFX 2D images before the 3D system then maps them to the model.

There are multiple ways in which 3D rendered output can get fuzzy and different ways to address some of these:

1. The texture is low resolution.

   - A fix is to provide a higher fidelity texture.
   - As you note there is a cost for fidelity in memory usage, larger images require more memory to store.
   - JavaFX images will likely be uncompressed bitmaps in memory (so quite large), but I don't know this for sure.
   - Internally modern graphics systems make use of texture compression (with support for this feature in hardware), which reduces the size of memory required for holding texture information.
   - I do not know if the JavaFX 2D images or the 3D implementation uses the texture compression features of hardware-accelerated graphics systems.
   - Most hardware graphic systems have an upper limit (e.g. 4096x4096) on the maximum size that an individual texture can be.
2. The model does not have enough polygons defined.

   - A 3D model is rendered as a collection of polygons made up of triangles.
   - By increasing the polygons, you can increase the fidelity of the model.
   - There is a cost to increasing the polygon count, regarding both memory storage and bandwidth required to support higher polygon counts.
   - Modern 3D graphics systems can usually support many thousands of polygons in a scene, even on (relatively) low-powered devices such as smartphones.
3. Polygons can be colored rather than texture mapped in a `diffuseMap`.

   - If each polygon is a single color, then you don't need a [`diffuseMap`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/PhongMaterial.html#diffuseMapProperty) at all, you can just set the [`diffuseColor`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/PhongMaterial.html#setDiffuseColor(javafx.scene.paint.Color)) of the polygon.
   - This approach will allow perfect fidelity as a polygon is scaled up or down as no texture needs to be resized.
4. A texture atlas can be used to represent the texture for a model efficiently.

   - For information on how to use a texture atlas, see:

     [How to create custom 3d model in JavaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8/19487494#19487494)
5. Smoothing groups need to be applied correctly.

   - When polygons in a model join at their edges, the 3D rendering needs hints on how the textures and colors should be blended in the polygons as the edge is approached.
   - The blending instructions for polygon edges are known as [face smoothing groups](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html#getFaceSmoothingGroups()).
   - If the smoothing groups are correctly defined, then the rendering of the faces near the edges of each face of the model will either be clearly defined with no color mixing or deliberately blurred to prevent the perception of sharp color transitions at the edges.
   - The choice of whether to use face smoothing on the joins of various faces is a decision the 3D modeler makes when defining the model, based on their requirements for the rendering of the model.
6. Scene antialiasing settings.

   - When a scene is defined, the developer can pass a [scene antialiasing](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/SceneAntialiasing.html) hint to the graphics system on how to define [antialiasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing) for a scene.
   - This will affect how colors are blended when multiple colors are mapped to different portions of a single pixel.
7. [Anisotropic filtering settings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_filtering).

   - Anisotropic filtering affects the quality of the display of a texture when it is shown at an angle to the viewer.
   - Anisotropic filtering can not be manually configured in JavaFX as of JavaFX 21, but may be configured for various applications in the video graphics driver settings for desktop settings, of the OS, and the graphics driver supports this.

#### Mipmapping

One technique that can be used for handling rendering different levels of detail in textures at different distances is [mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap).

> A high-resolution mipmap image is used for high-density samples, such as for objects close to the camera; lower-resolution images are used as the object appears farther away.

Mipmaps are a common technique for the efficient rendering of close and far objects (at the cost of some additional storage space or calculations to represent or calculate the textures at different levels of detail).  JavaFX has some logic to determine if the textures it is using are mipmapped, but, from this (currently, fairly recent) 2023 [post on the openjfx-dev forum](https://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.org/msg07722.html):

> You can either give your own set of scaled down images, or have them be generated for you by the graphics pipeline. Right now the implementation is partially set for mipmaps (there is a flag saying if they should be used or not), but at the end they are not used.

So, unfortunately, you can't just create your textures as mipmaps and apply them to your 3D model (which is a common approach to 3D modeling).  You could calculate the distances yourself in code, creating multiple material implementations with different textures at different level of detail and applying an appropriate material based on distance, but this is a poor substitute for native support for the feature.  You could try to create [your own Material class to handle that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622856/can-we-implement-our-own-materials-in-javafx), but, currently, that would be difficult.

#### Some advice

Depending on what you are doing, some of the items above are things you don't need to worry about.  Usually, you want a `BALANCED` setting for anti-aliasing when you define your scene and allow the OS and graphics driver to select an appropriate anisotropic filtering setting for your application implicitly.

You can use standardized formats and modeling systems to create and represent both 3D models and their textures.  This is recommended for any sizable 3D application.  For instance, the [fxyz](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/tree/master/FXyz-Importers/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/importers) library for JavaFX contains importers for some common 3D formats such as `obj`, `stl`, and Maya, as well as a JavaFX-specific FXML format.  [Interactive Mesh](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html) also have some importers. Those importers will define a model with appropriate texture maps and face-smoothing groups.  There are extensive free and commercial libraries of 3D models in those formats that you can import into JavaFX and use if you wish.  Unless you are a skilled 3D modeler, I recommend working with pre-defined models rather than trying to create your own.

For Minecraft-style resources in particular (given that you mention Minecraft in your question), if you google "Minecraft resource packs" you will find numerous resources for Minecraft.  You could create a Minecraft resource importer that imports such resource packs into a JavaFX application.  There may already be such an importer in existence on the web (I don't know).  There will be general Java importers for Minecraft information in existence because Minecraft was originally coded in Java.

#### Texture filtering

The reason for the extreme blurriness on your image is that, for 3D texturing, JavaFX (as of the 21 version) is hardcoded to use linear filtering for scaling textures.  You are applying a low-resolution texture to a large object, so the linear interpolation of colors as the texture is scaled up to fit the displayed surface results in blurry textures.

OpenGL and other 3D systems support multiple different modes for filtering textures, such as linear filtering as currently used in JavaFX, but also mipmapping as discussed above, and nearest neighbor filtering.  However, the JavaFX API currently has no way to set the filtering method to be applied to 3D textures to anything other than the default linear filtering.

Linear filtering is good for photorealistic rendering where you want colors to blend, but not so good for scaling up low-resolution 8-bit textures (e.g. max size 256x256) that you want to retain the blockiness of as they are scaled up.

A [description of various filtering techniques](https://docs.derivative.ca/Texture_Filtering#:%7E:text=Nearest%20filtering%20will%20make%20the,the%20GPU%20is%20currently%20sampling.), including nearest neighbor filtering, which is probably the kind of filtering you would prefer for your application.

> **Nearest** - Nearest filtering will just take the pixel color of the
> single pixel that is closest to the texture coordinates it is
> currently trying to sample at. Nearest filtering will make the image
> look more pixelated, but can be useful when trying to get pixel
> perfection.
>
> **Linear** - Linear filtering, also known as interpolation, will blend of
> the 4 pixels closest to the coordinate where the GPU is currently
> sampling. The blend is a linear blend that will give more weight to
> the pixels that the coordinate is closest to.
>
> **Mipmap Linear** - Mipmap linear, also known as Trilinear, is Linear
> Filtering, with the addition of sampling and blending between two
> different mipmap levels.

You can see what different scaling algorithms render like in this [sample image scaling gallery (which includes nearest neighbor)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_gallery_of_image_scaling_algorithms).  The discussion in this [developer email chain](https://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.org/msg07722.html) indicates that nearest neighbor filtering for JavaFX 3D may be a feature under consideration for implementation in a future JavaFX version.

#### Resources

James Weaver provides a presentation on how to apply textures to a cube, I won't reiterate it here, but encourage you to review it, see especially pages 26 to 30:

- https://www.slideshare.net/jpt1122/con2221-weaver-exploringjavafx3d

  (The link has some annoying advertising, unfortunately).

The presentation covers topics such as defining a mesh, and applying UV maps and face smoothing groups to a cube model.  This provides a practical demonstration of some of the concepts mentioned in the background section.

#### Related questions

- [How to create custom 3d model in JavaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8/19487494#19487494)
- [How to make sense of JavaFX triangle mesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960368/how-to-make-sense-of-javafx-triangle-mesh/19962622#19962622)
- [How to create 3d shape from STL in JavaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462571/how-to-create-3d-shape-from-stl-in-javafx-8/19464333#19464333)
- [Is it possible to create 3d model in JavaFX 8 without texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573105/is-it-possible-to-create-3d-model-in-javafx-8-without-texture/19574340#19574340)
- [How to color some triangles in a TriangleMesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305387/how-to-color-some-triangles-in-a-trianglemesh/69308521#69308521)

#### Example

I'll select a single technique, although your question about getting a quality image at different viewing distances could be solved in multiple ways.

The example creates Minecraft-style 3D block art from a 2D sprite sheet type PNG.

The approach is to create a box to represent each pixel.  Each box is colored the same color as the corresponding pixel in the sprite sheet.  This is done by setting the `diffuseColor` of the box.

This example doesn't apply UV-mapped texture to the box as a `diffuseImage`.  Just creating colored boxes is an easier way of generating a 3D model, rather than creating UV-mapped 3D models, unless you have an applicable 3D model and importer handy that you can load up into a `MeshView`.

The example 2D input image I have is drawn at a scale of ten pixels to one, so I downsample the image to a single pixel per color before I create the 3D blocks from it.

*Sample output*

[image: screenshot]

*HeroApp.java*

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class HeroApp extends Application {
    private static final Color INDIA_INK = Color.rgb(60,61,76);
    private static final double S = 1_000;
    private static final Point3D Y_AXIS = new Point3D(0, 1, 0);
    private static final Duration ROTATION_PERIOD = Duration.seconds(10);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();

        HeroFactory heroFactory = new HeroFactory();
        Node hero = heroFactory.spawn3DHero();

        Group root = new Group(hero);
        center(hero, S);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, S, S, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setFill(INDIA_INK);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        rotate(hero);
    }

    private static void rotate(Node node) {
        RotateTransition animation = new RotateTransition(ROTATION_PERIOD, node);

        animation.setAxis(Y_AXIS);
        animation.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        animation.setFromAngle(0);
        animation.setToAngle(360);
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();
    }

    private void center(Node node, double s) {
        Bounds bounds = node.getBoundsInLocal();
        node.setTranslateX((s - bounds.getWidth()) / 2);
        node.setTranslateY((s - bounds.getHeight()) / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*HeroFactory.java*

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;

import java.util.Objects;

public class HeroFactory {
    private static final String HERO_IMAGE_RESOURCE = "hero.png";
    private static final int BLOCK_DIMENSION = 10;
    private static final int BLOCK_DEPTH = BLOCK_DIMENSION * 3;
    private static final int IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE = 10;
    private final Image heroImage;

    public HeroFactory() {
        heroImage = downSample(HERO_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
    }

    public Node spawn2DHero() {
        return new ImageView(heroImage);
    }

    public Node spawn3DHero() {
        return toBlocks(heroImage);
    }

    private Node toBlocks(Image image) {
        Group group = new Group();

        PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();

        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                Color color = reader.getColor(x, y);
                if (color.equals(Color.TRANSPARENT)) {
                    continue;
                }

                Box block = new Box(BLOCK_DIMENSION, BLOCK_DIMENSION, BLOCK_DEPTH);
                block.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(color));
                block.setTranslateX(x * BLOCK_DIMENSION);
                block.setTranslateY(y * BLOCK_DIMENSION);
                group.getChildren().add(block);
            }
        }

        return group;
    }

    // our hero image source is blocky art with each block 10 pixels wide
    // resample it to convert it to standard 1 pixel art.
    private static Image downSample(String imageResource) {
        String imageSource = Objects.requireNonNull(
                HeroApp.class.getResource(
                        imageResource
                )
        ).toExternalForm();

        Image image = new Image(imageSource);
        PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
        WritableImage imageOut = new WritableImage(
                (int) image.getWidth() / IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE,
                (int) image.getHeight() / IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE
        );
        PixelWriter writer = imageOut.getPixelWriter();
        for (int x = IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE / 2; x < image.getWidth(); x += IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE) {
            for (int y = IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE / 2; y < image.getHeight(); y += IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE) {
                writer.setColor(x / IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE, y / IMAGE_PIXEL_SIZE, reader.getColor(x, y));
            }
        }

        return imageOut;
    }
}
```

*hero.png*

[image: hero.png]

#### Adding animation

If your sprite sheet is for animated sprites, you could [animate the movement of the sprite](https://netopyr.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-sprite-animation-with-javafx/).  The linked article is for animated 2D sprites, but animated 3D sprites would be no similar, as you can see from the additional example below.  The explosion image used in the example is the same as the one in [this sprite animation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440980/how-show-specific-part-of-an-image-in-javafx/23442447#23442447).

*ExplosionApp.java*

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ExplosionApp extends Application {
    private static final Color INDIA_INK = Color.rgb(60,61,76);
    private static final double S = 900;
    private static final Point3D Y_AXIS = new Point3D(0, 1, 0);
    private static final Duration ROTATION_PERIOD = Duration.seconds(30);
    private static final String EXPLOSION_IMAGE_RESOURCE = "explosion.png";
    private static final int NUM_CELLS_PER_EXPLOSION = 6;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();

        Image explosionImage = new Image(Objects.requireNonNull(ExplosionApp.class.getResourceAsStream(EXPLOSION_IMAGE_RESOURCE)));
        Sprite3D explosion = new Sprite3D(explosionImage, NUM_CELLS_PER_EXPLOSION);

        Group root = new Group(explosion);
        center(explosion, S);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, S, S, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setFill(INDIA_INK);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        explosion.animate();
        rotate(explosion);
    }

    private static void rotate(Node node) {
        RotateTransition animation = new RotateTransition(ROTATION_PERIOD, node);

        animation.setAxis(Y_AXIS);
        animation.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        animation.setFromAngle(0);
        animation.setToAngle(360);
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();
    }

    private void center(Sprite3D sprite3D, double s) {
        sprite3D.setTranslateX((s - sprite3D.getSprite3DWidth()) / 2);
        sprite3D.setTranslateY((s - sprite3D.getSprite3DHeight()) / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Sprite3D.java*

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.util.Duration;

class Sprite3D extends Group {
    public static final int BLOCK_DIMENSION = 5;
    public static final int BLOCK_DEPTH = BLOCK_DIMENSION * 3;
    private static final Duration FRAME_TIME = Duration.seconds(.5);

    private final int numCells;
    private final double cellWidth;
    private final double cellHeight;
    private Group[] blocks;

    public Sprite3D(Image spriteSheet, int numCells) {
        this.numCells = numCells;

        cellWidth  = spriteSheet.getWidth() / numCells;
        cellHeight = spriteSheet.getHeight();

        toBlocks(spriteSheet);
    }

    public double getSprite3DWidth() {
        return cellWidth * BLOCK_DIMENSION;
    }

    public double getSprite3DHeight() {
        return cellHeight * BLOCK_DIMENSION;
    }

    private void toBlocks(Image image) {
        PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();

        blocks = new Group[numCells];

        for (int frameCounter = 0; frameCounter < numCells; frameCounter++) {
            final Rectangle2D cellClip = new Rectangle2D(
                    frameCounter * cellWidth, 0,
                    cellWidth, cellHeight
            );

            blocks[frameCounter] = new Group();

            int xOffset = (int) cellClip.getMinX();
            int xMax = (int) cellClip.getMaxX();
            int yOffset = (int) cellClip.getMinY();
            int yMax = (int) cellClip.getMaxY();

            for (int x = xOffset;  x < xMax; x++) {
                for (int y = yOffset; y < yMax; y++) {
                    Color color = reader.getColor(x, y);
                    if (color.equals(Color.TRANSPARENT)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Box block = new Box(BLOCK_DIMENSION, BLOCK_DIMENSION, BLOCK_DEPTH);
                    block.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(color));
                    block.setTranslateX((x - xOffset) * BLOCK_DIMENSION);
                    block.setTranslateY((y - yOffset) * BLOCK_DIMENSION);
                    blocks[frameCounter].getChildren().add(block);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void animate() {
        final IntegerProperty frameCounter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(FRAME_TIME, event -> {
                    frameCounter.set((frameCounter.get() + 1) % numCells);
                    getChildren().setAll(blocks[frameCounter.get()]);
                })
        );
        animation.setCycleCount(numCells);
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();
    }
}
```